# Entity vs DTO in CQRS

Tags: design-patterns, entity, domain-driven-design, dto, cqrs

In a normal DDD project I expect the Entities retrieved from a repository to be sent from the Domain Layer to the Application Layer as a DTO.

It seems that one reason of CQRS to exist is that the queries needed by the application layer (mostly read operations) are different from the ones needed by the domain layer. So it seems that even a query result of the same object might be different among layers.

Within my domain layer I am already mapping query results into domain entities. I am confused about some CQRS examples mapping query results straight into DTOs skipping their matching entities.

Suppose that a database returns:

```
{"person": {
  "id:": 5323423,
  "name": "John",
  "family_name": "Smith"
  ...
}}
```

However the entity layout maps *family name* as *surname*:

```
class Person
{
   Identity id;
   String name;
   String surname;
}
```

If this happens in some CQRS examples I have seen, the extracted DTO will look different, causing a conflict when matching an entity with its DTO. How are these conflicts resolved? It looks to me that any DTO (related with an Entity) should always be generated from its Entity. However in that case, the freedom to perform different type of queries in the Application Layer is lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is you don't map entities to DTOs. The DTOs are defined by what that specific context needs and that becomes the query/read model. When an entity is updated an event handler will use it to update the read model too.

So basically the read model is generated and updated from all needed entities (1 ore more), usually in an incremental manner.

Comment: In my example if the DTO from the read model is modified by the user (family name), the GUI will raise a command with that DTO that will reach the Domain Layer. Inside the Domain Layer I can read or generate DTO, but only can save back to the database an Entity. Therefore I assumed when saving modifications, that a DTO must be mapped to its entity. If you just update the new value into the Entity from the database, how is the modification saved into the DB without going through the Entity and the mismatching field names?

Comment: Read model generation isn't a part of the Domain layer, rather a Services or Application, but clearly not Domain as it's about a model use outside it. The modification is saved into the Db but any change generates a domain event. The event handler will update the read model then send it to a query repository to be persisted. If you want everything to be done sync at the repository layer, then you can change there the read model (still calling a service) and return only after it's updated.

Comment: Sadly my line of tough is still classic DDD. With plain DDD I map anything from/to DB with a repo in my Domain Layer using Entity objects. Do you mean that the query repository (write/command model?)  (plain repo in DDD before CQRS) can take not only an Entity as input but also different "shaped" DTOs from such entity? Being that way, still a data mapper is only for an Entity, but its DTOs from a DB can persist future Entity values without data mapping as long as an ID is provided??? (very near my Aha! moment)

Comment: DDD and CQRS are different concepts working together. The DDD repo deals with domain entities, the query repo is just a repository (service if you feel better) for read (view) models. Neither DDD nor CQRS care about the db. CQRS really means only separate read mdoel form write model. DDD only 'sees' repositories regardless how they are implemented (db or not). The read DTO is an object needed by that context (view model for ex). It's generated by a service which will take directly the Entity and popoulate the the bits the DTO requires. Entity != DTO, they don't know about each other.

Comment: As a general advice I say just: think decoupled. Because this is what you're trying to achieve with CQRS. Domain has its own (write)model, UI(reporting etc) has its own (read)model. A third party (service, event handlers) will use the write model to update the relevant read models.  THe write/read model evolve according to their context needs. The 3rd party just handles the 'wiring', usually by mapping.

Comment: OK, any field naming change of my "Person" example will not affect my Entity objects, since these are maintained with some type of data mapping. "Person" as Entity in my Domain Layer is clearly not the same as "DTO related with a Person", the DTO might share the same ID field as the Entity... but! my DTOs so far never had any type of data mapping that isolates DB changes from my code (because only Entities did and DTOs came out only from Entities)... or do they? (trying to share the same data mapper between DTO and Entity would ease things)  Anyways, you already deserve accepting your answer.

Comment: ops!... the query/read model spits out DTOs... my previous repositories gave out results "normalized" through a data mapper. So porting my DDD repo (Entity based) to a CQRS Query Model (DTO based) means that I should "normalize my DTOs" too... Aha!

Answer (score 7):

Totally aggreed with @MikeSW, just add an graph(borrowed from axon-framework) to explain the architecture.

[image]

The readmodel is driven by query use-case, you could consider it as the output of the command operations.